# Numpy similar way of indexing as matlab

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array

```
a = np.repeat([i for i in range(10)], 1000)
```

and another numpy array

```
b = np.arange(10, 20)
```

How do I insert the values of `b` into `a` based on index? So that all 0 = 10, 1 = 11 and so on. Is there something similar to matlab where you can say `b(a)`

Comment: Isn't it just `b[a]` ?

Comment: Sorry. My bad, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.repeat([i for i in range(10)], 1000)
b = np.arange(10, 20)
a=b[a]
print(a)
```

The output:
[10 10 10 ... 19 19 19]